# Formula for Adding Time expressed as decimal

Tags: numerical-methods, transformation

If I record the duration of an event that was 97 minutes as 1.37 and then record the duration of another event that was 162 minutes as 2.42 and then add the two together to get 3.79, is there a formula I could apply to this total to transform it to 4.19 that does not involve splitting the fractional part from the integer? A really simple equation might look like:

$$
time_{base60} = x(time_{base60 as base10})
$$

I was trying to use radians and degrees but remembered I have no idea how to use either. But something like that would be what I'm curious about, rather than simply converting the fractional from decimal back to base 60 and adding it to the integer.

Comment: Why would you use this representation?  The sum of two numbers' representations doesn't in general equal the representation of their sum. For example, 105 minutes + 115 minutes = 220 minutes but $1.45 + 1.55 = 3$.

Comment: Someone glanced on this idea the other day in conversation and it got caught in my head, so I thought I'd ask. And I know they don't have the same sum, that's why my question is if there is a direct way to derive the wrong representation to the correct value but still in the wrong representation. I'm asking because I'll never have a definitive answer until I've asked.

Comment: My example shows that if you add some numbers and the result is $3$, there is *no way to tell* if the answer represents $3$ hours or $220$ minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple if you apply the concepts of [vedic maths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_Mathematics_%28book%29). 
Lets try adding, 1hr 37min and 2hr 42 min
write them as 
 137
+242
= 379

add a time constant of 40 to the subtotal which gives 419, which is your answer. 4hr 19 minutes. No matter what the hours and minutes are, just add the 40 time constant to the sub
total.
Here is a link of where i found it http://e-vedicmaths.blogspot.in/2011/09/adding-time-using-ancient-menthod.html

Comment: This is only correct if there's a carry involved between hours and minutes. For example, if you wanted to add 1 hour and 27 minutes to 2 hours and 14 minutes, your method would give 127+214+40=381 (or 3 hours and 81 minutes??), but the actual correct answer is 3 hours and 41 minutes.

Comment: +1 for not only indulging my question but also having an answer from 3000 years ago that works at least some of the time. Jury is still out on how the Vedas dealt with Micah's example.

Comment: @Anthony Actually, as the Wikipedia page notes, the book cited was first published in 1965, a mere 48 years ago at the time of this comment. But anyway here is the fix for this "method".  If the sum of the minutes is greater than 60, add 0.4 to the result. If not, don't. In other words, add the minutes separately, carry the hours, then convert the result back to this "decimal" representation.